# Laravel routing auto-resolve parameters

Tags: php, laravel, orm

This might be a beginner question, but there is something I don't quite understand in my Laravel application. 
I'm using id on routes and I'm trying to make laravel automatically fetching the correspondant objects in the DB. It works well for some models :
In the routing :

```
 Route::get('/project/{project}', 'ProjectController@useProject');
```

and in the controller

```
 public function useProject(Request $request, Project $project)
```

and after that I have my "project" fetched from the DB

```
protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 9
      'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
   ...
public 'exists' => boolean true
```

In another part of the code, where I'm using the same routing structure on a different model, the auto-resolve doesn't seem to happen

Routing:

```
  Route::get('/build/{testscenario}','JavaController@create');
```

Controller:

```
    public function create(Request $request, TestScenario $scenario){
```

And the result:

```
  protected 'attributes' => 
     array (size=0)
       empty
   ...
  public 'exists' => boolean false
```

Both models are using a "id" column as a primary key.
What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to do a route model binding? refer this for an example https://scotch.io/tutorials/cleaner-laravel-controllers-with-route-model-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the model implicit binding, so I would recommend reading this [section from the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#implicit-binding).

You need to match the variable names:

```
Route::get('/build/{testscenario}','JavaController@create');
```

And in your controller:

```
public function create(Request $request, TestScenario $testscenario){
```

Comment: Yes I found the problem shortly after posting the question. Stupid mistake :) But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah nevermind. Found the solution. It's a naming problem.

```
   Route::get('/build/{testscenario}','JavaController@create');
```

And

```
  public function create(Request $request, TestScenario $scenario){
```

Parameters should have the same name (ie either "testscenario" or "scenario").

Answer (score 0):

As per model binding rules,you have to keep same name for segment and your instance.For details https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

So your routes and controller will be 

  `Route::get('/build/{testscenario}','JavaController@create');
  public function create(Request $request, TestScenario $testscenario)`